# почему не работает функция autoslider js

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById('left').onclick = sliderLeft;
 var left = 0;
 autoSlider();
 function autoSlider(){
    setTimeout(sliderLeft , 1000);
 }
 function sliderLeft(){
    var polosa = document.getElementById('sas');
    
    left = left + 473;
    if (left > 0){
        left = -473;
    }
    polosa.style.left = left +'px' ;
 }
 document.getElementById('right').onclick = sliderRight;
 var left = 0;
 function sliderRight(){
    var polosa = document.getElementById('sas');
    
    left = left - 473;
    if (left < -1200){
        left = -473;
    }
    polosa.style.left = left +'px' ;
 }
```

нужно чтобы слайдер срабатывал по таймеру почему не работает незнаю

Comment: Вы, наверное, хотели вызвать `setInterval`, а не `setTimeout`?

Comment: я по видео урокам смотрел там setTimeOut

Comment: хороший видео урок, где слайд перелистывается по таймауту.